# Successor of a natural number (Terence Tao)

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

I need help. I have two doubts.

I bring below excerpt from page 16, from Analysis I (Third Edition), by Terence Tao.

1) Is the author there guaranteeing the uniqueness of the successor of any natural number whatsoever?

2) What does the author mean by saying that, in language C, n ++ redefines the value of n to be its successor?

"To define the natural numbers, we will use two fundamenmtal concepts: the zero number 0, and the increment operation. In deference to modern computer languages, we will use n++ to denote the increment or successor of n, thus for instance 3++ = 4, (3++)++ = 5, etc. This is slightly different usage from that in computer languages such as C, where n++ actually redefines the value of n to be its successor; however in mathematics we try not to define a variable more than once in any given setting, as it can often lead to confusion; many of the statements which were true for the old value of the variable can now become false, and vice versa."

Comment: The successor is always unique, though I don't think that passage says so. You can ignore that tidbit about redefinition, he's just saying that he's not doing that here.

Comment: the sucessor is evaluated by a function, hence it is unique. About the second thing: in many programming languages $n++$ means that now the value of $n$ is $n+1$. That is, it changes the value of the variable $n$.

Comment: Regarding the C bit: in the programming language C, if you have a variable $n$ and write $n++$, then after that the *new* value of $n$ is the previous value, plus one. (for instance: `int n = 0; n++;` leads to $n$ "containing" the value $1$.) Here, T.Tao says he won't do that "reassignement": once a variable is "given" a value, that value stays forever.

Comment: One way to get the successor is n+=1

Comment: Is not the mentioned increment operation a function from N to N?

Answer (score 1):

He is referring to the standard effect in procedural languages that a line of code can appear to be mathematical nonsense. For example:

- n = n + 1;

This is not a statement of equality, it is an "instruction" (or "order" etc) with the following semantics:

1. Find the value of $n+1$.
2. Assign this value to $n$.

So after executing this instruction, the value of $n$ is increased by 1. (Unfortunately, the most usual term used in programming to refer to this thing which is not a statement is: (!) "statement".)

Similarly in C (or C++), the $++$ operator has the same effect as the above code, thus:

- $x++$

This increments $x$, but actually gives the value of $x$ *before* incrementing. Thus strictly speaking, using "x++" to refer to the successor value is completely wrong, because in C the expression $3++ == 4$ has the value FALSE. (== is the equality operator) Nevertheless, we can see that it may be a convenient notation.

Comment: <nitpick> `3++ == 4` wouldn't compile. The operand of the post increment operator must be a modifiable lvalue, which an integer literal like `3` isn't. But `int m = 3; if (m++ == 4) { /* some code */ }` isn't as snappy. </nitpick>